# Adding Colorpicker Field To Category

Tags: categories, jquery, wp-enqueue-script, color-picker

I want to add a custom field to my categories where the user can color code them. I've added the field but I want to use built in colorpicker (either tinyMCE or the farbtastic) to give the user an easy way to pick colors. I can't figure out how to add the functionality yet though, here's what I have so far:

**Category Field Setup**

```
/** Add New Field To Category **/
function extra_category_fields( $tag ) {
    $t_id = $tag->term_id;
    $cat_meta = get_option( "category_$t_id");
?>
<tr class="form-field">
<th scope="row" valign="top"><label for="cat_Image_url"><?php _e('Category Image Url'); ?></label></th>
<td>
<input type="text" name="Cat_meta[bgc]" id="colorinput" size="3" style="width:20%;" value="<?php echo $cat_meta['bgc'] ? $cat_meta['bgc'] : '#fff'; ?>" class="my-color-field" />
<div id="colorpicker"></div><br />
            <span class="description"><?php _e('Can't Think of A Desc Yet, Suggestions?'); ?></span>
                <br />
        </td>
</tr>
<?php
}
add_action ( 'category_add_form_fields', 'extra_category_fields');

/** Save Category Meta **/
function save_extra_category_fileds( $term_id ) {
    if ( isset( $_POST['Cat_meta'] ) ) {
        $t_id = $term_id;
        $cat_meta = get_option( "category_$t_id");
        $cat_keys = array_keys($_POST['Cat_meta']);
            foreach ($cat_keys as $key){
            if (isset($_POST['Cat_meta'][$key])){
                $cat_meta[$key] = $_POST['Cat_meta'][$key];
            }
        }
        //save the option array
        update_option( "category_$t_id", $cat_meta );
    }
}
add_action ( 'edited_category', 'save_extra_category_fileds');
```

**Colorpicker Script (Farbtastic) - Doesn't Work**

```
/** Enqueue Color Picker **/
function farbtastic_scripts() {
  wp_enqueue_script( 'jQuery' );
  wp_enqueue_style( 'farbtastic' );
  wp_enqueue_script( 'farbtastic' );

  ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        jQuery(document).ready(function() {
            jQuery('#colorpicker').hide();
            jQuery('#colorpicker').farbtastic("#colorinput");
            jQuery("#colorinput").click(function(){jQuery('#colorpicker').slideToggle()});
        });

    </script>
  <?php
}
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'farbtastic_scripts' );
```

**:: Edit ::** If it makes it any easier, I do have the "Advanced Custom Fields" plugin which has a colorpicker option. I'm looking to see if it would be easier to use that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This has been updated for WordPress 4+ with the introduction of Term Meta. The code is heavily commented.

**:: My Functions - functions.php ::**

The below function is to display the colorpicker on the "Add New Category" screen:

```
/**
 * Add new colorpicker field to "Add new Category" screen
 * - https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/taxonomy_add_form_fields/
 *
 * @param String $taxonomy
 *
 * @return void
 */
function colorpicker_field_add_new_category( $taxonomy ) {

  ?>

    <div class="form-field term-colorpicker-wrap">
        <label for="term-colorpicker">Category Color</label>
        <input name="_category_color" value="#ffffff" class="colorpicker" id="term-colorpicker" />
        <p>This is the field description where you can tell the user how the color is used in the theme.</p>
    </div>

  <?php

}
add_action( 'category_add_form_fields', 'colorpicker_field_add_new_category' );  // Variable Hook Name
```

The below function will add the colorpicker field to the "Edit Category" screen:

```
/**
 * Add new colopicker field to "Edit Category" screen
 * - https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/taxonomy_add_form_fields/
 *
 * @param WP_Term_Object $term
 *
 * @return void
 */
function colorpicker_field_edit_category( $term ) {

    $color = get_term_meta( $term->term_id, '_category_color', true );
    $color = ( ! empty( $color ) ) ? "#{$color}" : '#ffffff';

  ?>

    <tr class="form-field term-colorpicker-wrap">
        <th scope="row"><label for="term-colorpicker">Severity Color</label></th>
        <td>
            <input name="_category_color" value="<?php echo $color; ?>" class="colorpicker" id="term-colorpicker" />
            <p class="description">This is the field description where you can tell the user how the color is used in the theme.</p>
        </td>
    </tr>

  <?php


}
add_action( 'category_edit_form_fields', 'colorpicker_field_edit_category' );   // Variable Hook Name
```

The below function will sanitize and save the term meta without the `#` but there is a separate function which will sanitize it with the hash called [`sanitize_hex_color()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/sanitize_hex_color/):

```
/**
 * Term Metadata - Save Created and Edited Term Metadata
 * - https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/created_taxonomy/
 * - https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/edited_taxonomy/
 *
 * @param Integer $term_id
 *
 * @return void
 */
function save_termmeta( $term_id ) {

    // Save term color if possible
    if( isset( $_POST['_category_color'] ) && ! empty( $_POST['_category_color'] ) ) {
        update_term_meta( $term_id, '_category_color', sanitize_hex_color_no_hash( $_POST['_category_color'] ) );
    } else {
        delete_term_meta( $term_id, '_category_color' );
    }

}
add_action( 'created_category', 'save_termmeta' );  // Variable Hook Name
add_action( 'edited_category',  'save_termmeta' );  // Variable Hook Name
```

Now that the fields are added and data is being saved we need to enqueue the script(s) that put the colorpicker in place. Do note that in the first conditional I test against the taxonomy I'm showing the field on.

```
/**
 * Enqueue colorpicker styles and scripts.
 * - https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/admin_enqueue_scripts/
 *
 * @return void
 */
function category_colorpicker_enqueue( $taxonomy ) {

    if( null !== ( $screen = get_current_screen() ) && 'edit-category' !== $screen->id ) {
        return;
    }

    // Colorpicker Scripts
    wp_enqueue_script( 'wp-color-picker' );

    // Colorpicker Styles
    wp_enqueue_style( 'wp-color-picker' );

}
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'category_colorpicker_enqueue' );
```

Finally, we need to initialize the colorpicker. Here I've chosen to just print it into the footer but it may be more beneficial, especially from a plugin perspective, to put this in an external file and enqueue it like a normal script.

```
/**
 * Print javascript to initialize the colorpicker
 * - https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/admin_print_scripts/
 *
 * @return void
 */
function colorpicker_init_inline() {

    if( null !== ( $screen = get_current_screen() ) && 'edit-category' !== $screen->id ) {
        return;
    }

  ?>

    <script>
        jQuery( document ).ready( function( $ ) {

            $( '.colorpicker' ).wpColorPicker();

        } ); // End Document Ready JQuery
    </script>

  <?php

}
add_action( 'admin_print_scripts', 'colorpicker_init_inline', 20 );
```

Comment: Thanks for this great solution. One problem I notice is that it does not seem to work (save correctly) when picking a color during the creation of a new category. But it does work when editing an existing category. Do you have this same problem?

Comment: Yeah, there's an extra function which you'll need to include (and I've edited above) which hooks into: `category_add_form_fields` and then you'll need to add the save field action hook `created_category` which I've also included above. Hopefully that works for you!