# Add Extra Category Field to CPT Categories

Tags: custom-post-types, categories, custom-field

So I'm able to add an extra field to my categories (A Color picker actually, to color code categories - pretty cool stuff [if anybody is interested](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/112866/adding-colorpicker-field-to-category)) but the extra field ONLY shows up under Posts. I have a CPT with its own category page and it doesn't show up there. Is there a way to only have the extra field show up under my CPT categories page? Do I need to hook into something different?

Here's what I'm doing now:

```
/** Add New Field To Category **/
function extra_category_fields( $tag ) {
    $t_id = $tag->term_id;
    $cat_meta = get_option( "category_$t_id" );
?>
<tr class="form-field">
    <th scope="row" valign="top"><label for="meta-color"><?php _e('Category Name Background Color'); ?></label></th>
    <td>
        <div id="colorpicker">
            <input type="text" name="cat_meta[catBG]" class="colorpicker" size="3" style="width:20%;" value="<?php echo (isset($cat_meta['catBG'])) ? $cat_meta['catBG'] : '#fff'; ?>" />
        </div>
            <br />
        <span class="description"><?php _e(''); ?></span>
            <br />
        </td>
</tr>
<?php
}
add_action ( 'category_add_form_fields', 'extra_category_fields');
add_action('category_edit_form_fields','extra_category_fields');
```

Comment: Have you created custom taxonomy for CPT?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the following hooks in your code to add it to event-category custom taxonomy.

```
add_action('event-category_edit_form_fields','extra_category_fields');  
add_action('event-category_add_form_fields','extra_category_fields');
```

Comment: I've seen this method before, like with managing post columns and such, does this work with most hooks? On that note, it doesn't seem to work - it removed them from Posts Categories but doesn't add them to my CPT Categories. Here's a pastebin with my [CPT, Taxonomy, and Categories Fields](http://pastebin.com/kccKpzcr) - it seems to be spelled correctly.

Comment: These are the WordPress hooks.

Comment: What's name of your CPT taxonomy?

Comment: I added it all to a pastebin file [Here](http://pastebin.com/kccKpzcr)

Comment: I have changed my code by referring your pastebin code. Test it now.

Comment: Oh gotcha, so not the CPT but the category taxonomy, that makes sense. Thanks!