# Set colors depending on category

Tags: categories, wp-query, query-posts

I have this function which outputs the last 6 posts of categories 1 and 2.

```
<ul>
<?php query_posts('cat=1,2&showposts=6'); ?>
<?php if ( have_posts() ) while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><strong><?php the_title(); ?></strong></a><br />
    <em><?php echo substr(get_the_excerpt(), 0,110); ?> ...</em>
    </li>
    <br />
<?php endwhile; ?>
</ul>
```

What I'd like to do is have the link to the article (for instance) red if it's from category 1 and green if it's from category 2. Can you help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting aside that you're incorrectly using `query_posts()`, the easiest solution is to add a call to [`post_class()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/post_class), to output post-specific classes, including `.category-{ID}` and `.category-{slug}`:

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    <li <?php post_class(); ?>><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><strong><?php the_title(); ?></strong></a><br />
    <em><?php echo substr(get_the_excerpt(), 0,110); ?> ...</em>
    </li>
    <br />
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Then, you can use CSS to target `li.category-{ID}`.

Comment: Can you elaborate more on why the use of query_posts is wrong? I didn't call an endif?

Comment: Please refer to [this question/answer regarding use of `WP_Query()`, `query_posts()`, and `pre_get_posts`](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/50761/when-to-use-wp-query-query-posts-and-pre-get-posts).

Answer (score 1):

This isn't really the most dynamic solution but you could do something like this:

```
<ul>
<?php query_posts('cat=1,2&showposts=6'); ?>
<?php if ( have_posts() ) while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

  <?php if($post->post_category == 1) : ?>
    <li style="color:red">
  <?php else : ?>
    <li style="color:green">
  <?php endif; ?>

        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><strong><?php the_title(); ?></strong></a><br />
        <em><?php echo substr(get_the_excerpt(), 0,110); ?> ...</em>
    </li>
    <br />
<?php endwhile; ?>
</ul>
```

Alternatively you could dynamically add a class for each category, here I'm basing it on `slug` but the best solution might be to base it on `term_id` [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_category#Return_Values)

```
<ul>
<?php query_posts('cat=1,2&showposts=6'); ?>
<?php if ( have_posts() ) while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    <?php $cat = get_the_category(); ?>
    <li class="catColor-<?php echo $cat->slug; ?>">
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><strong><?php the_title(); ?></strong></a><br />
        <em><?php echo substr(get_the_excerpt(), 0,110); ?> ...</em>
    </li>
    <br />
<?php endwhile; ?>
</ul>
```

If you are familiar enough with wordpress / php you could take a shot at adding a custom field to your categories to add colors there. [Here's How I did That](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/112866/adding-colorpicker-field-to-category)