# How to define a custom hierarchy for terms?

Tags: wp-query, custom-taxonomy, taxonomy, terms, hierarchical

I've got terms defined under a custom taxonomy. I want the terms to be pseudo-hierarchical, in that I want each term to be able to define a "parent" term that can be selected from a drop-down, but I do not want to use the other terms as the options (which is the default behavior). Instead of using the same list of terms as potential parents, I want to use a custom data source.

I see in the `wp-admin/edit-tag-form.php` file, starting on line 165, the following code that generates the drop-down list of parent terms:

```
$dropdown_args = apply_filters(
    'taxonomy_parent_dropdown_args',
    $dropdown_args,
    $taxonomy,
    'edit'
);
wp_dropdown_categories($dropdown_args);
```

And based on the documentation for [wp_dropdown_categories](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_dropdown_categories/), it looks like I can set up a hook into [get_terms](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/get_terms/) and then, theoretically, make use of [WP_Term_Query](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_term_query/) to write my own custom SQL. (Although based on that code, I'm thinking I actually need to hook into [taxonomy_parent_dropdown_args](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/taxonomy_parent_dropdown_args/) instead.) In any case, my question is: how do I do this?

I'm still relatively new to plugin development, and I haven't found any concrete examples of someone overriding the resultset of `get_terms` by using the `WP_Term_Query` class to define a custom query. I'm actually thinking about using an entirely new table, created by my plugin.

For example, suppose I wanted to query something like:

```
SELECT id, name FROM custom_parent_table WHERE taxonomy = %s
```

How would I go about implementing this with `WP_Term_Query`? (Or, if I'm off base and haven't got the right understanding of how these hooks and classes interact, how would I do it regardless?)

Comment: Maybe you can [use a walker](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_dropdown_categories/#comment-1823) but I'm not sure if you would be able to change the order at that point.

Comment: Just a thought, but could it be that it would make more sense to work with a non-hierarchical taxonomy. Then add a form field and work with term meta data. Instead of playing around with the parent drop down. Kind of like shown [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/112866/adding-colorpicker-field-to-category?noredirect=1&lq=1), coincidently by @Howdy_McGee.

Comment: @Nicolai - that's a really good idea. The more I think about this, the more I think I was trying to over-complicate the solution. Adding a new field seems like the better way to go.

Comment: @SoaperGEM My pleasure. In the end it really only depends on what you need for your use case. That I can't know of course, which is why just offered another idea.